# How to change a sprite with a script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and C#. I'm trying to make the sprite of "bird" change when he dies in unity. I tried following some tutorials but it doesn't work, so now I'm just trying to make the sprite change when "A" is pressed, but it still doesn't work. Is it a problem of the script or of the sprite?
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeSprite : MonoBehaviour

{

    public Sprite deadBird;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = deadBird;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTd9W.png

Comment: Looks right to me so far.  Does the BirdScript maybe control the sprite too?  If so, it could be overwriting your changes in ChangeSprite.

Comment: Since you have an `Animator` there -> does any of your states/clips hold a key frame on the sprite? => If so, then the Animator will overrule any changes via code on that property!

Answer (score 0):

I think @derHugo is correct, if you have an Animator then that will most likely overwrite any change you try and do. To fix this, you can use that animator and create an animation that is the deadBird. once you have that, connect it to the animator controller from the normal state. in that connection you can create and set a new animator boolean like "isDead" and set it to switch to the dead animation is the bool is true. then change your code from

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = deadBird;
```

To

```
anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>() //place this instead of the bird sprite
anim.SetBool("isDead", true); //place this in the if statement
```

Hope that helps! it's much cleaner to go through the animator as it allows for easier changes as you build your game.

Comment: ok dude thanks you, but do i have to create the animator boolean "isDead" in a script inside the deadBird animation ?

Comment: No need, in the animator panel you should see the option to hit a little "+" button and add a boolean in there. Then in the script you'll have to reference it by calling the animator (something like public Animator anim) or make it private and get it by using Get Component which is the cleaner way of doing it. Then change the book by doing anim.SetBool("is dead", true)